# JPQL - custom query to delete a database entry and return a property different from the deleted entry's ID

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

In JPQL, is there a way to delete a row from a database and return a property of the deleted row?

For example, given a database that stores books, I want to delete a book of a given ID and return the book-title.

I was trying to implement a custom query for this in my BookRepository, which extends the JpaRepository:

```
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {

  @Transactional
  @Modifying
  @Query("DELETE FROM Book b WHERE b.id = ?1")
  String deleteBookById(Long id);
```

The Query is lacking the part, which returns the book-title. Can someone help me out, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but HQL will get this at some point in the future. If you are using PostgreSQL, you can use the `returning` clause for this purpose:

```
@Transactional
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM Book b WHERE b.id = ?1 RETURNING title", native = true)
String deleteBookById(Long id);
```

Comment: allright, thx a lot Christian! For now, I am using MySQL, which doesn't have the `returning` clause, as far as I know. My code now relies on two database calls, one finding the book title and another one deleting the book.

Comment: That's great, and this is also how Hibernate will emulate this feature eventually on DBMS that don't support the native syntax